# LibXML doesn't find any nodes for my xpath expression

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xpath, libxml2

I'm using xpath and LibXML in an iPhone app to find some nodes in an xml document. I'm a noob in xpath so probably i am doing something wrong.
Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUserByEmailResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetUserByEmailResult>
        <id>4006</id>
        <name>Kudor Gyozo</name>
        <email/>
        <image/>
        <facebookId>0</facebookId>
      </GetUserByEmailResult>
    </GetUserByEmailResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The xpath expression is `//GetUserByEmailResult`. No nodes are returned. I expect to get `<GetUserByEmailResult>` back. If I test the same stuff [here](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm) it works ok.

UPDATE1: This is what i get back from a .net web service. Is there a way to ignore namespaces in libxml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetUserByEmailResult` element is in the `http://tempuri.org/` namespace so you would need to add that namespace to your XPath search.

You can do so using the `xmlXPathRegisterNs` function:

```
xmlXPathRegisterNs(context,  BAD_CAST "temp", BAD_CAST "http://tempuri.org/");
```

Then your XPath would have to be changed to

```
//temp:GetUserByEmailResult
```

Comment: Yes this works thanks a lot. BTW is there a way to ignore namespaces?

Comment: @kudor gyozo: Yes, you can ignore namespaces by only checking the local names in your XPath expressions as suggested in Wrikken's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the iphone library, but you'll probably have to declare the namsepace / prefix somewhere: If you register 'http://tempuri.org/' with 'someprefix', you can search for:

```
//someprefix:GetUserByEmailResult
```

A possible workaround is (but not advisable):

```
//*[local-name()='GetUserByEmailResult']
```